# Redirect category to cms page magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

I have created a *Category* which is in my main menu. I wanted to redirect it to a *CMS Page* when click on it. More specifically:

- The *Category*'s URL Key is `apps.html`
- The *CMS Page*'s URL Key is `apps`

Currently, I have the following URL configuration:

[image]

I added the following *URL Rewrite* rule:

[image]

However, when I click on the *Category*, it still goes to the *Category* associated URL page. I've also reindexed it.

Any idea about why the redirection is not working as expected?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you can create a category normally, so create a **CMS Block** with the content of your page and set these options below on the category:

[image: CMS Block Page on Magento 2]

Comment: Ok Thanks.. That means I need to create a static block for contact us  form and assign it to category as above?

Comment: Yes, you can use this tutorial to add a contact form on static block. https://rafaelstz.github.io/magento2/Magento-2-Create-contact-page-CMS.html